# npm works only with --legacy-peer-deps but I want to fix dependencies to get rid of that parameter. How?

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I have an angularJS project, recently it cannot be compiled without `--legacy-peer-deps`.

I know which packages cause error, because when running `npm install` I see them listed here:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @stryker-mutator/core@6.3.1
//and so on
```

But now I would like to replace the versions that cannot be found  in package.json, so I will be able to run simply `npm install` without additional parameters.

Is there any verbose mode for

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

so i can check which packages are found and used, then replace them in `package.json`?

Comment: Take this as a sign that it's time to properly upgrade _all_ your dependencies? That said, there's always `--loglevel verbose`.